# Chrome Form Submit stops jQuery "click" function (works in FF & IE8)

Tags: jquery, forms, google-app-engine, google-chrome, blockui

I have a form where when the user clicks the submit button, blockUI is triggered and shows a loader GIF as the browser waits for the server to load the resulting page (a model is being run on the server and can take many seconds before the results page loads, so the blockUI is there to let the user know the submit button is working).

ISSUE:  In Chrome after clicking "submit" button blockUI appears, but the loader.gif is shown as a broken image, but in FF and IE8 this works perfectly fine.  Is there something special about how Chrome handles a form submission where it stops all other HTTP requests (for the loader.gif) or something??

EDIT:  This issue occurs also when a link is clicked, which triggers blockUI with the loader.gif.  In IE8 the GIF loads, in FF it sometimes loads, and in Chrome it shows a broken image icon.  I think the HTTP request for a new page is breaking the loading of the GIF.  Any suggestions???

Form is simple, the "submit" button is actually a `type="button"` so I can control the form submit with Javascript:

```
<input class="input_button" type="button" value="Submit">
```

The Javacsript/jQuery is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#form1").validate({
    rules: {
    upfile: "required"  
            }
    });

    var browserWidth = $(window).width();
    var browserHeight = $(window).height();
    var winleft = (browserWidth / 2) - 220 + "px";
    var wintop = (browserHeight / 2) - 30 + "px";

    $('input[value="Submit"]').click(function () {
        $("#form1").submit();
        $.blockUI({
        css:{ "top":""+wintop+"", "left":""+winleft+"", "padding": "30px 20px", "width": "400px", "height": "60px", "border": "0 none", "border-radius": "4px", "-webkit-border-radius": "4px", "-moz-border-radius": "4px", "box-shadow": "3px 3px 15px #333", "-webkit-box-shadow": "3px 3px 15px #333", "-moz-box-shadow": "3px 3px 15px #333" },
        message: '<h2 class="popup_header">Processing Request...</h2><br><img src="/images/loader.gif" style="margin-top:-16px">'
        });
    });

});
</script>
```

The `.validate()` works fine.

Comment: Any error in console like "cannot access local file"? Check image path and specifically protocol used

Comment: No console errors or logs.  If you "inspect" the element (loader.gif) and click its image path, the gif loads fine in a new tab.  It seems that Chrome won't let the HTTP request to load the loader.gif go through

Comment: Same behaviour if you use absolute path for image?

Comment: Same behavior with absolute image path

Comment: Sounds like a simple image caching issue to me.  Have you dumped the browser cache yet?  Have you tried it again in other installations of Chrome on other machines?

Comment: @Sparky I have tried it on different computers.  It seems that Chrome is stopping the HTTP request for the image before it loads onscreen.

Comment: This issue isn't isolated to a form and submit button.  I also have a link that when clicked loads up a page that auto-runs a models and displays results.  When clicking this link, blockUI is triggered with the same loader.gif.  Again, this works in IE8, but not Chrome.  In this specific situation, it only works sometimes in FF.  
It seems to be that the HTTP request for the new page stops the loader.gif from being loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you preload the image in your js before your click handler, that should resolve your Chrome issue:

```
  var loadImg = new Image();
  loadImg.src = "/images/loader.gif";
```

However, if you're really not too attached to your loader GIF, I would recommend ditching the GIF approach all together and utilizing Spin.js http://fgnass.github.com/spin.js/

There are plenty of known issues with blockUI and images on submit actions, and Spin.js works nicely in all browsers with blockUI.

Comment: Thanks, I was unaware of the BlockUI & images & submit issues.  I actually am kinda attached to my spinner GIF, but I'll check out spin.js